# Replacing a number plus a symbol with the same number minus the symbol in Python

Tags: python

Alright, so I've been having a bit of trouble with this. I want to replace a (as the title says) number followed by a symbol with that same number without the symbol. For example, say I have the object:

```
{
    title = "Hello",
    description = 9,
    followup = [
        {
            title = "World",
            description = 0,
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I go about replacing the "9," with just "9" and the "0," with just "0"? The entire object is stored as plain text, so it's a string.

I tried looking at regex, but that doesn't seem to allow me to store the number in the wildcard.

Comment: There is a simple regular expression solution, but this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you are trying to do? Why do you need to make this change?

Comment: I'm trying to strip a JSON object of all its formatting (and in the process flattening it), removing all the quotation marks, commas, and brackets. I've got everything but what this question asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with a back reference, like so:

```
import re

s = '''
{
    title = "Hello",
    description = 9,
    followup = [
        {
            title = "World",
            description = 0,
        }
    ]
}'''

s = re.sub(r'(\s+\d+),', r'\1', s)
print(s)
```